# bitcoin payment high fees

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, transaction-fees

I am using `bitcoin-rpc` and everytime i create an invoice for the client to pay, i create a new address. Payment is ok, i get the money after a cron.php sees that all confirmations are above 3, but then when i try to send my money back to my big wallet i see 200 300 usd in fees

`bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "MY_WALLET" 0.1 "" "" true`

I see on blockchain that everything was sent from each and every address that i have created

ADDRESS1 ... 0.05

ADDRESS2 ... 0.08

ADDRESS2 ... 0.028

... and so on

How can i send everything from one big address and pay only 20$ usd fee?

I think i pay per vbyte for what i have read ... but i want to send internally with low or no fees or something. Can i send coins internally to one big wallet?

I mean don't think that big payment gateways that do the same thing and create an address for every invoice but pay such amounts of fees.

Thank you.

Comment: How many UTXOs are you trying to spend in this transaction? or in different words, How many inputs does it have? Did you specify fee rate for this transaction using `fee_rate` in `sendtoaddress` or use `estimate_mode` and `conf_target`? Do you have other UTXOs in wallet with more than 0.1 BTC?

Comment: i think it is `estimate_mode` and as imputs i have 30 40 50 100 ... a lot , explain more about `UTXO` or a link ...

Answer (score 1):

> **Can i send coins internally to one big wallet?**

No.

By internal you mean without communicating with the Bitcoin network and without involving external miners.

All Bitcoin transactions which move money from one set of Bitcoin addresses to another Bitcoin address are external in the sense that they must be recorded on the blockchain and therefore must incur transaction fees.

Comment: ok, i understand, but how to implement a payment systems when i transfer all i got into my big wallet and after that i lose a lot of money? if i use a big payment gateway service, they send with 10 ... 20 usd fee ... how they do it ?